# Custom object reduce values for similar key in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, functional-programming, reduce

I have created a dictionary of unique keys using the Dictionary(grouping:by) from a fetchRequest Cored Data model object in the form of [GeneralCategory]. Now I would like to figure out a way to reduce a specific parameter within the Dictionary value (in this case a boolean that I have converted to a double).

```
struct GeneralCategory {
    var drank: Bool?
    var dateOnly: String?
    var otherParam1
    var otherParam2
    etc
}

let groupedDict = Dictionary(grouping: coreDataFetch) { ($0.dateOnly!) }.reduce(into: [String: Double]()) { $0[$1.key] = Double($1.1.count) }

// returns the reduced parameter across all keys, not per key
```

How would I go about reducing the values *per* key so that I would go from

```
[["7-7-20": 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],["7-8-20": 0.0, 1.0], ["7-9-20": 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ,1.0]]

to 

[["7-7-20": 2.0],["7-8-20": 1.0], ["7-9-20": 2.0]]
```

Thanks in advance for any advice, I hope I was clear in the question (first post).

Comment: The example you gave doesn't actually match the requirement you raised. Please clarify.

Comment: And what do you mean by **(in this case a boolean that I have converted to a double**?How did you even convert a `Bool` to `Double`. Your requirement is not clear enough.

Comment: Apologies, the bool value measures whether or not an individual drank and I have a counter that adds += 1 for every instance that happens. In order to apply the reduce closure I have to convert the bool value to a double. But thanks for replying within seven seconds that's impressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`mapValues(_:)`** and **`reduce(_:_:)`** to get the expected result.

In the `reduce(_:_:)`, you simply need to check if `drank` is `true` and increase the counter accordingly.

```
let groupedDict = Dictionary(grouping: coreDataFetch) { $0.dateOnly }.mapValues {
    $0.reduce(0.0) { (result, category) -> Double in
        if let drank = category.drank, drank {
            return result + 1.0
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

**Note:** I don't see any reason to use `Double` here. You can use `Int` type instead.

Comment: Great. Do accept (tick on left) if the answer helped. Happy coding..

Comment: You bet. Also the Double value is a requirement for the Charts library BarChartDataEntry (Double: Double) since i'm using the data to populate a Barnhart.